# excel to csv with 16 digit numbers

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

Good morning All. I am new to powershell script. I am trying to convert multiple .xlsx files to .csv files. I have found the script online, but I have a problem with credit card numbers. I am getting last digit is getting round off (16th digit of the card number). Here is the script. Can any one help me with this. Could someone explain the commands as well.

```
foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem "C:\ExcelFiles")) {

  $newname = $file.FullName -replace '\.xlsx$', '.csv'
  $ExcelWB = new-object -comobject excel.application
  $Workbook = $ExcelWB.Workbooks.Open($file.FullName) 
  $Workbook.SaveAs($newname,6)
  $Workbook.Close($false)
  $ExcelWB.quit()

}
```

Comment: Excel will store only 15 sig digit numbers.  the data will need to be stored and treated as text strings

Comment: I saved the card number as text string in xlsx file. But, csv is giving me 15 digit (scientific) numbers. Is there a way to work around this please.

Comment: are you re-opening the text file in excel or a text reader?  Try opening in Notebook or other text reader.  Is the number correct?  If so then you will need to import into excel through the wizards and make that column text on the import.  If not then you are using a mask and not a true text.